# Prisma Mysql backend, update recipe upsert without where

Tags: javascript, prisma

I am attempting to do an update on my database for the following api call on my express.js server.

The issue I am running into is that on the front-end I am able to add in new recipe_ingredients, when this happens I then in turn have a missing id because it is not present in the database yet.

With this issue. I do not know how to update the recipe and then create new records when they do not have their corresponding IDs to be able to find them in the recipe_ingredient table.

This is because I also update the api call  to always have the where: {id: ingredient.id} which then returns where: {id: undefined} which is also not valid. which throws errors of the following

```
Argument `where` of type Recipe_IngredientWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` arguments.
```

***Below is the Recipe_Ingredients objects that are passed in through JSON, You can see that the 2nd record is actually a new item without a id.***

```
  Recipe_Ingredient: [
    {
      id: 1,
      recipeId: '1',
      ingredientId: 1,
      quantity: 25,
      measurement: 'lb'
    },
    {
      recipeId: '1',
      ingredientId: '2',
      quantity: '2',
      measurement: 'tsp'
    }
  ],
```

***The api call for updating my recipe***

```
app.put('/api/recipes/:id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log( req.body);
    try {
      const recipeId = Number(req.params.id);
      const {
        name,
        description,
        steps,
        notes,
        Recipe_Ingredient,
      } = req.body;
  
      const updatedRecipe = await prisma.recipe.update({
        where: {
          id: recipeId,
        },
        data: {
          name: name,
          description: description,
          steps: steps,
          notes: notes,
          Recipe_Ingredient: {
            upsert: Recipe_Ingredient.map((ingredient) => ({
                where: ingredient.id ? { id: ingredient.id } : undefined, // Use the id field of Recipe_Ingredient
              update: {
                ingredientId: ingredient.ingredientId,
                quantity: ingredient.quantity,
                measurement: ingredient.measurement,
              },
              create: {
                ingredientId: ingredient.ingredientId,
                quantity: ingredient.quantity,
                measurement: ingredient.measurement,
              },
            })),
          },
          // Include any other fields you want to update
        },
        include: {
          Recipe_Ingredient: true,
          // Include any other relations you want to include in the response
        },
      });
      
      
      
      
  
      res.status(200).json(updatedRecipe);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to update recipe' });
    }
  });
```

***Server Response for Prisma***

```
PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.recipe.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: 1
  },
  data: {
    name: "Summer Sausage",
    description: "Fantastic Summer Sausage recipe for the ages",
    steps: {
      stepsList: [
        "Grind the meat, alternating",
        "Season the meat",
        "mix the meat1",
        "mix the meat2",
        "mix the meat3",
        "mix the meat4",
        "mix the meat5",
        "mix the meat6",
        "mix the meat7"
      ]
    },
    notes: {
      notesList: [
        "Grind the meat, alternating",
        "Season the meat",
        "mix the meat1",
        "mix the meat2",
        "mix the meat3",
        "mix the meat4",
        "mix the meat5",
        "mix the meat6",
        "mix the meat7"
      ]
    },
    Recipe_Ingredient: {
      upsert: [
        {
          where: {
            id: 1
          },
          update: {
            ingredientId: 1,
            quantity: 25,
            measurement: "lb"
          },
          create: {
            ingredientId: 1,
            quantity: 25,
            measurement: "lb"
          }
        },
        {
          where: undefined,
          update: {
            ingredientId: "2",
            quantity: "2",
            measurement: "tsp"
          },
          create: {
            ingredientId: "2",
            quantity: "2",
            measurement: "tsp"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  include: {
    Recipe_Ingredient: true
  }
}

Argument `where` is missing.
    at Ur (/volume1/web/RecipeWebsite/Server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:115:5803)
    at zr.handleRequestError (/volume1/web/RecipeWebsite/Server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:8007)
    at zr.handleAndLogRequestError (/volume1/web/RecipeWebsite/Server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7697)
    at zr.request (/volume1/web/RecipeWebsite/Server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7307)
    at async file:///volume1/web/RecipeWebsite/Server/Server.js:98:29 {
  clientVersion: '5.0.0'
}
```

***This is my Schema.***

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Recipe {
  id                Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  name              String
  description       String?
  notes             Json?
  steps             Json
  quantity          Float?
  measurement       String?
  Recipe_Ingredient Recipe_Ingredient[]
  userID            Int?
  User              User?               @relation(fields: [userID], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull)
  createdAt         DateTime            @default(now())
  img               Img?
}

model Img {
  id           Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  recipe       Recipe?     @relation(fields: [recipeId], references: [id])
  recipeId     Int?        @unique
  ingredient   Ingredient? @relation(fields: [ingredientId], references: [id])
  ingredientId Int?        @unique
  img          Bytes
}

model Ingredient {
  id                Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  name              String
  quantity          Float?
  measurement       String?
  Cost              Float?
  Recipe_Ingredient Recipe_Ingredient[]
  createdAt         DateTime            @default(now())
  Img               Img?
}

model Recipe_Ingredient {
  id           Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  recipe       Recipe     @relation(fields: [recipeId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  recipeId     Int
  ingredient   Ingredient @relation(fields: [ingredientId], references: [id])
  ingredientId Int
  quantity     Float
  measurement  String
}

model User {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String
  age          Int
  email        String   @unique
  password     String
  writtenPosts Recipe[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

looked further into the documentation, the upsert command has a limitation where if you do not have the id in a where clause it will not do the find/create. So this was not able to work, as shown below.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#update-or-create-records

This was resolved by doing the following command where I seperated out the two arrays and then updated/created individually based on those two different arrays.

As shown below.

```
app.put('/api/recipes/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const recipeId = Number(req.params.id);
      const {
        name,
        description,
        steps,
        notes,
        Recipe_Ingredient,
      } = req.body;
  
      const recipe_ingredientNoID = [];
      const recipe_ingredientsID = [];
  
      Recipe_Ingredient.forEach((ingredient) => {
        if (ingredient.id) {
          recipe_ingredientsID.push(ingredient);
        } else {
          recipe_ingredientNoID.push(ingredient);
        }
      });
  
      const updatedRecipe = await prisma.recipe.update({
        where: {
          id: recipeId,
        },
        data: {
          name: name,
          description: description,
          steps: steps,
          notes: notes,
          Recipe_Ingredient: {
            updateMany: recipe_ingredientsID.map((ingredient) => ({
              where: { id: ingredient.id },
              data: {
                ingredientId: Number(ingredient.ingredientId),
                quantity: parseFloat(ingredient.quantity),
                measurement: ingredient.measurement,
              },
            })),
            create: recipe_ingredientNoID.map((ingredient) => ({
              ingredientId: Number(ingredient.ingredientId),
              quantity: parseFloat(ingredient.quantity),
              measurement: ingredient.measurement,
            })),
          },
        },
        include: {
          Recipe_Ingredient: true,
        },
      });
  
      res.status(200).json(updatedRecipe);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to update recipe' });
    }
  });
```